# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///android_asset/www/index.html was not found

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdk-tools

I have a cordova app (that i'm building for Android) that I have signed using the keytools on the command line and installed this onto my Android device.

Whenever I open the app on my phone I get the following error:

```
Application Error
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
```

My phone has an internet connection so there is an active mobile internet connection - can anyone help in debugging the problem?

I have come across a number of fixes that relate to moving remote assets however I cannot see in my app where I have any links to a remote URL.

Is there a way I can do a 'stack-trace' to allow me to pin-point the exact point this Application Error is being thrown within my app?

**Any** tips at all would be appreciated

-- update -- 
Here is the adb log that is generated when in the emulator

For anyone else that this may help I used the following to output the emulator log to a file:- (the double >> is needed to append data to the file)

```
adb -e logcat >> emulator.log
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e53abb7eb089950ac4e5

-- update --
My AndroidManifest.xml file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.myapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>
```

-- update --
Within my platforms 'android' folder is a 'assets' folder - this has the following structure:

```
www/
_where-is-www.txt
  www/css
  www/img
  www/js
  www/res
  www/app.html
  www/cordova.js
  www/cordova_plugins.js
  www/index.php
```

There doesn't appear to be an index.html - even though the cordova setup states an index.html file... I cannot understand why it would be doing this.

**NOTE** :
I am creating a cordova app, adding a Android platform, then copying my existing www folder from another directory of the existing app (that has been developed and released to the Play store so works ok) - then finally doing the build. Not sure why index.html should be showing... any ideas??

Comment: Could you post post the debug log? Use ADB to view the debug log using: `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S` in CLI. Alternatively, you can use Chrome's remotely debugging a `WebView` facility if you have a device having Anrdoid 4.4+(Kitkat or higher) - developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: added the logfile - not sure what any of it means to be honest :) I hope some Android/Cordova experts can help me out

Comment: Could you check if `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` is added to your config.xml file?

Comment: I have posed the AndroidManifest.xml - this has the INTERNET permission added to that xml file

Comment: Umm, this should work then. If you are loading any javascript from a CDN, then you'd get an error **only if** there's no internet connection. But you have the permissions too.

Comment: it is a really weird one... i'll keep at it will find the issue eventually thanks for the advice though

Comment: So what does your `/android_asset/www/index.html` contains?

Comment: @JamesWong - I have a folder /platforms/android/assets/www - this contains an index.php but not a index.html. Note this folder is autogenerated by cordova when doing the 'cordova platform add android' command.

Comment: `index.php`? How did you get a PHP file? Cordova can only process HTML, CSS and JS files

Comment: @Zabs There's your problem, it has to be an HTML file. If you want to load an external website, you can either iframe it from the HTML or redirect the user to it.

Comment: I created the `assets` folder under `src\AppMain`.(Note: The icon will change if you are developing for Native Android) then under that created a `www` folder and dumped my HTML there. 
Everything started working once i set the `uses-permission`. I hope this helps anyone who is stuck with this. Note: its `android_asset` when referencing in `http://`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should run `cordova build android` before `cordova run android` or make it simple by running `cordova build android && cordova run android --device`
PS: don't forget `sudo` if you work on mac

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the ionic commands to fix this error:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android
```

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-err-file-not-found-file-android-asset-www-index-html/91629/2